# sagemath: convert R Element to float

Tags: python, r, sage

How can I extract a numerical part of an R Element?

I'm using the R interface in sagemath. And I would like to get float or int values.

I have an R Element, that is an object of class `sage.interfaces.r.RElement`, that contains a value that I would like to extract.

For example, given the following element:

```
 x = [1] 6.5
```

How may I extract the 6.5 value as a float?

```
float(x)
```

does not work.

```
float(str(x).split()[1])
```

seems excessively crude.

For any interested in generating the example R Element, it my be done in [a sagemathcell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) with the following code:

```
aList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
fences = r.quantile(aList)
x = fences[[3]]
print (type(x))
print (x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `x` back to a float in Sage with `x.sage()`.

If `x` is defined as in the question:

```
sage: s = x.sage()
sage: s
6.5
sage: type(s)
<type 'float'>
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. And it seems like it may be useful in other situations.